# Adding elements to array in a for loop, empty array after loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

So I encountered the following problem: I have an array with keys used to encrypt a string. A for loop goes through the array, encrypts the string with the current key and then pushes the encrypted string into a new array. Here the code:

```
var enc_gmessages = ['start'];

for(i = 0; i < pubkeys.length; i++) {
    var pubkey = pubkeys[i];

    if(pubkey != 'no' && pubkey != null) {
        var publicKey = openpgp.key.readArmored(pubkey);
        openpgp.encryptMessage(publicKey.keys, content).then(function(pgp_gmessage) {
            //string encrypted successfully
            console.log(pgp_gmessage);
            enc_gmessages.push(pgp_gmessage);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('error');
        });
    }
}
alert(enc_gmessages);
```

While the string gets encrypted successfully (and logged in the console) if there's a valid public key, the array only contains the 'start' element after the for loop. Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The encryption routine is asynchronous. The code uses a web worker (not sure what it does in Node). Thus the `for` loop finishes before anything has been encrypted.

Comment: you need to wrap this up in a function that returns a `Promise`.

Comment: what happens if you move alert(enc_gmessages); to the line immediately after your enc_gmessages.push(pgp_gmessage); ?

Comment: @Tokn there's already a `console.log()` call in there.

Comment: @Pointy I can't see it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to obtain a value from an asynchronous operation before it has completed.

That's not possible, so what you should do is create a new Promise whose eventual result will be the expected array of messages:

```
function getMessages(pubkeys) {

    // get an array of Promises for each valid key - each element is 
    // a promise that will be "resolved" with the encrypted message
    var promises = pubkeys.filter(function(pubkey) {
        return pubkey != null && pubkey != 'no';
    }).map(function(pubkey) {
        var publicKey = openpgp.key.readArmored(pubkey);
        return openpgp.encryptMessage(publicKey.keys, content);
    });

    // then once all are resolved, return a new promise that
    // is resolved with the desired array
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function(messages) {
        return ['start'].concat(messages);
    });
}
```

Although you could `.catch` after the `Promise.all` line, it would be more usual to catch any failures at the point this was invoked.

If the "start" element in the returned array was only there for debugging and isn't actually required, just replace the entire return block with `return Promise.all(promises)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the promises system is causing trouble here.
You push elements into the array in the callback of each promises returned by `openpgp.encryptMessage(...)`, so the loop ends before any action takes actually place.

Comment: given the OP's already using promises, this is _not_ the way to wait for them all to finish.  That's what `Promise.all()` is for.

Comment: This code has the same problem - that `encryptionCompleted()` function doesn't really do anything; the returned function is ignored.